# Error cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string' on string filepath

Tags: c#

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.FooterRow;
string filename = ((FileUpload)row.FindControl("FileUpload1")).FileName.ToString();
string filepath = ((FileUpload)row.FindControl("FileUpload1")).PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/") + filename;
```

Comment: A title and a portion of code........that's telling us a whole lot of nothing about your problem........

Comment: Your example code doesn't compile on the filepath line, there's a close bracket missing somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx) doesn't return a `string`, or anything else. If you want the path in its own variable,

```
string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/") + filename;
((FileUpload)row.FindControl("FileUpload1")).PostedFile.SaveAs(filepath);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is reasonable because in the right hand of `filepath` you have a method that is `void`, which means that doesn't return anything. The method is the `SaveAs`. So, since `SaveAs` doesn't return any value, what are you tyring to assign to the `filepath`.

If you want to get the `filepath`, you could just get it as you already pass it to the `SaveAs` method.

```
string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/") + filename;
```